# Augment makefile compilation switches for specific files

Tags: gnu-make

CFLAGS environment variable can be used to pass compilation switches to Makefile from the outside world without modifying the file itself. Is there a way to pass switches **only for one specific source file**?

In my case I'd like to suppress gcc warning for several files **but not for all** and the Makefile is automatically generated by IDE so I cannot edit it.

Answer (score 0):

We can't answer this question given the lack of details.

However you can add NEW makefiles to be parsed along with the old makefiles, without changing the old makefiles.  For example, you can run this:

```
make -f Makefile -f ExtraMakefile
```

and create your own ExtraMakefile that contains any extra makefile text you want and make will read them both, in that order.

Answer (score 0):

Please find below way which will help you to pass extra compiler flags and assign value into it based on your conditions.
You can pass switches by creating a new variable , 
Ex: CCFLAGS_EXTRASWITCH and use this flag in CCFLAGS variable.

```
# Append CC_FLAGS with variable CCFLAGS_EXTRASWITCH which will be used to 
# pass extra switches. Value of CCFLAGS_EXTRASWITCH  you can assign
# to empty or some switches based on conditions/files that you have
CC_FLAGS   = $(CCFLAGS_EXTRASWITCH) \
             ... \   # Other default compiler flags that already exists. Keep as it is
```

Comment: This way I will have to edit the Makefile which I cannot do. I can only modify environment variables or run pre-build steps before Makefile runs.

Comment: @jackhub : IF CC_FLAGS is your environmental variable then you can put values inside this environmental based on your file types.The option that you can peform is to update your environmental variable from a small script if it is possible to integrate in your IDE before compilation

Comment: If I add compilation switch to CC_FLAGS it will affect compilation of all C files. What I'm looking for is the way to add compilation switch only for one file.

Comment: @jackhab : you would need to include your own small makefile as it is not possible other wise